# QML - Display "Next" button to move to next TextField on a mobile keyboard

Tags: mobile, keyboard, qml, textfield, qtquick2

How can I force my keyboard layout to display the "Next" button in QML ? ( Like in a standard HTML form ) 
I don't want to display a "OK" button ( which means that you're about to validate the form .. )

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`EnterKey` attached property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-enterkey.html) introduced in Qt 5.6:

```
import QtQuick 2.6

TextInput {
    EnterKey.type: Qt.EnterKeyNext
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TextInput {
    id: txtInput  
    Component.onCompleted: {  
    EnterKeyAction.actionId = EnterKeyAction.Next  
    EnterKeyAction.label = "Next"  
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you not used Qt Virtual Keyboard. So you can set action button type through `EnterKey.type` attached property (available types are Go, Search, Send, Next,...).
Also you need to handle ***return*** button pressed signal to do what you want. For example, sending data. In your case you want just switch focus to next control.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 1.12

Column {
    TextField {
        id: field1
        KeyNavigation.tab: field2
        activeFocusOnTab: true
        Keys.onReturnPressed: KeyNavigation.tab.forceActiveFocus();
    }
    TextField {
        id: field2
        KeyNavigation.tab: field3
        activeFocusOnTab: true
        Keys.onReturnPressed: KeyNavigation.tab.forceActiveFocus();
    }
    TextField {
        id: field3
        KeyNavigation.tab: field1
        activeFocusOnTab: true
        Keys.onReturnPressed: KeyNavigation.tab.forceActiveFocus();
    }
}
```

I handled `returnPressed` signal to switch focus. Also I made it possible to switch using `TAB` key for Desktop platforms.